# 301 redirect that carries a variable to new URL (using htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, parameters

I need to redirect the pages of an old website to a new website using htaccess. Some of the old site's URLs have a parameter with a variable. That variable ideally would be carried over to the new URL. So for example,

Old: http://`old-website.com`/index4.php?show=1590

New: http://`new-website.com`/performance/1590

Notice the variable "1590" is carried to the new URLs. I'm still learning regex and htaccess but can get this working right. Here is where I left off...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=/index4.php?show=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?(index4.php)?$ http://showfile.fm/performance/%1? [L,R=301]
```

I also need to get the homepage and other pages without variables to redirect to specific pages. I'm not sure how you would stack those other rules - if there is a necessary order.